# How to test puppeteer code by saving html page locally?

Tags: html, testing, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer for scraping data and I want to test the puppeteer code by saving the actual html pages locally i.e by using `setContent` method.

After setting the content how I can check that my **scraping** code is correctly interacting with locally saved html page?

Comment: Welcome to SO! More details seem necessary--if your target page is a simple .html file with few or no dependencies, that's pretty easy, just grab the page source and copy it locally, but the typical modern app has hundreds of dependencies and complex client-server actions, so it's not so easy to reproduce locally. Please define "correctly interacting" here -- what are you trying to do, specifically?

Comment: yes so basically I want to perform login operation on page